# Can I resize icons on the launcher to smaller than 32 pixels?

Tags: unity, launcher

Is there a way to get smaller icons in Unity that are less than 32 pixels?
I would like to set it at something like 24 or 26, because 32 is too big on a 1366x786 screen.